# Is the following statement true and why/why not?

Tags: number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Assume $1 \le n$. And $x \in Z_n = \{0,1,2,..n-1\}$. Assume in addition that for some $k>0$,

$kx = 0 \pmod n$,  i.e. $\,n\mid kx$.
And assume $k\mid n$.

Is it then true that $\gcd(n,x)=n/k $, where $\gcd=$ greatest common divisor? Note by the assumptions, $n/k$ must divide both $n$ and $x$, but how can I show that this is in fact the greatest common divisor? Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you suppose $gcd(n,x)=1$, as another answer states it, it is clear.

If you don't, then the result is false : take $n=16$, $k=4$ and $x=8$.

Comment: I edited, see the new counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

If $n|kx$ and $gcd(n,x)=1$, then $n|k$. Adding the assumption that $k|n$, you get that $n=k$.

So indeed $1=gcd(n,x)=n/k$, but it is a strange way of writing it since $k=n$ !

Comment: I messed up sorry, It should be gcd=n/k. I have edited now

Comment: This is the same, since $k=n$ !

Comment: gcd(n,x)=1 is no longer true. I have corrected it.